# wicked_pdf multi page document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

I have a scenario where i need to generate a multipage pdf based on an array of objects.

Following is my models:

```
# Member has_many certificates

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :certificates, dependent: :destroy

  before_save :set_expiry

  def self.delete_expired
    where(expire_at: Date.today).destroy_all
  end

  private
    def set_expiry
      self.expire_at = 15.days.from_now
    end
end

# certificate belongs_to member
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :certificate_type
  belongs_to :company

  def company_name
    company.name
  end

  def page_orientation
    company_name == 'CompanyA' ? 'Landscape' : 'Portrait'
  end

  def page_height
    company_name == 'CompanyA' ? '10.5in' : '11in'
  end

  def page_width
    company_name == 'CompanyA' ? '7in' : '8.5in'
  end
end

# each type can have many certificates
class CertificateType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certificates
end
```

The user flow is something like following:

- User uploads an excel file with records of Members. The system store the records.
- User can then generate a certificate for a single member. (already working).
- User can generate certificates in bulk for multiple of all members uploaded.

I have a custom form where i'm creating certificate objects (checkbox selection) and then submitting the form. The controller receives a hash of certificate objects. I have to loop through all the objects one by one to create the certificate for it's associated member. The problem is that each certificate has it's own template and some custom page layout settings like orientation, width and height. I want to generate one single pdf file with multiple pages where each page is a single certificate. I'm stuck at where and how should i pass the page layout settings for each individual certificate. I tried render_to_string in my controller and tried to set page layout options there but it doesn't seem to work. I need some suggestion or pointers here.

Comment: Is using an external utility, such as `poppler-utils` an option (i.e. do you have control over the server)? If it's on Heroku or something, it may not be. If so, I can give you some detail on how to use this in your scenario.

Comment: @fdisk it's not Heroku. I'm using digital ocean i guess that should work.

Answer (score 5):

Building on @fdisk 's answer, but using the Ruby native [`combine_pdf` gem](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf)... you could try:

```
require 'combine_pdf'

merged_certificates = CombinePDF.new

@member.certificates.each do |certificate|
  pdf_data = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string(something, layout: some_layout))
  merged_certificates  << CombinePDF.parse(pdf_data)
end

send_data merged_certificates.to_pdf, filename: 'mypdf.pdf' #...
```

Comment: `merged_certificates  << CombinePDF.new.parse(pdf_data)` should be `merged_certificates  << CombinePDF.parse(pdf_data)`. Your answer helped me a lot, btw! Thanks!

Comment: @NelsonSenna , thanks for the catch :) and I'm happy this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to generate multiple PDFs in a background job and save the final merged file as an attachment in my model. So I did it like this:

```
def generate_and_send
 begin
  final_pdf = pdf_from_html.to_pdf
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(pdf_path)) unless Dir.exists?(File.dirname(pdf_path))
  File.open(pdf_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << final_pdf
  end
  @object.attachment = File.open pdf_path
  @object.save
 rescue => e
  notifiy_status('error')
 end
```

And my pdf generator and merger was set-up like this

```
   def pdf_from_html
    #Will generate each page in separate to prevent memory overflow
    #Then joins the pages
    final_pdf = CombinePDF.new
    pages = @pages_to_print.select{ |k, v| v == '1'}.keys
    pages.each do |page|
      page_html = render("#{page}") #This method defines the layout based on the page
      pdf_from_page = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(page_html)
      final_pdf << CombinePDF.parse(pdf_from_page, allow_optional_content: true)
    end
    final_pdf
  end
```

Tips: Remember to use the method `.to_pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an option, I would recommend installing `poppler-utils` via your distro's package manager (`yum`, `apt-get`, `dnf`, etc.). After that, save each certificate as a `Tempfile`:

```
require 'shellwords'

certificates = @member.certificates.map do |certificate|
  Tempfile.open(["cert", ".pdf"]) { |file| file << WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string(something, layout: some_layout)) }
end

paths = certificates.map { |cert| cert.path.shellescape }

@final_pdf = Tempfile.new(["cert", ".pdf"])
@final_pdf.close
%x[pdfunite #{paths} #{@final_pdf.path.shellescape}]
```

That `@final_pdf` object should contain the merged individual certificates. I've also made a simple [gem](https://github.com/rickpr/jpdfunite) to handle these cases, but it may have a bit of extra overhead you're not looking for (it's designed to create combined PDF files with nested bookmarks).

Comment: You could probably do the same with a native Ruby solution such as [CombinePDF](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf).